# How to scatter an entire 2D array to all processes using MPI

Tags: mpi

As the title suggests I'm looking to take an entire 2D array and scatter that whole array to the other processes. Here is the code I am using:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int i,j,size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Usage : pairwise numberOfSequences lengthOfSequences\n eg. pairwise 10000 50\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&M);

    char strings[N][M+1];


    if(rank == 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            //Here I read from a file into the array strings and this works
            scanf("%s\n",strings[i]);
            printf("Rank:%d  i value:%d # %s\n",rank,i,strings[i]);
        }
    }   

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    char array_for_all[N][M+1];

    //I think here my parameters are wrong for Scatter.
    MPI_Scatter(strings, N*(M+1),MPI_CHAR,array_for_all, N*(M+1), MPI_CHAR, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Rank:%d  i value:%d # %s\n",rank,i,array_for_all[i]);
    }
```

I'm not to sure if I am implementing the scatter correctly. I dont want to send parts of the array to each process, I want to send the whole array to each process or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to send all of the data to everyone, that sounds an awful lot like a Bcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As signaled by @Wesley , the right way to go is to use `MPI_Bcast()`, to broadcast the data over all processus.  The first argument should be the pointer to the data : `&strings[0][0]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int N,M;
    int i,j,size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Usage : pairwise numberOfSequences lengthOfSequences\n eg. pairwise 10000 50\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&M);
    char strings[N][M+1];


    if(rank == 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            //Here I read from a file into the array strings and this works
            scanf("%s",strings[i]);
            printf("Rank:%d  i value:%d # %s\n",rank,i,strings[i]);fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("input over, now output :\n");fflush(stdout);
    }   

    //I think here my parameters are wrong for Scatter.
    MPI_Bcast(&strings[0][0],N*(M+1), MPI_CHAR, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // MPI_Scatter(strings, N*(M+1),MPI_CHAR,array_for_all, N*(M+1), MPI_CHAR, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Rank:%d  i value:%d # %s\n",rank,i,strings[i]);fflush(stdout);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```